# vc++ can't find #include <unistd.h> #include <getopt.h>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to get some image processing code working in MS VC++ 2010 express. The code uses opencv so I've downloaded that and installed it. I've created a project and added the opencv files to the project. I've 2 probs that the compiler can't open `#include <unistd.h>` and `#include <getopt.h>`. Any ideas how to include these headers in my project. Sorry but I'm new to c++ and usually program in android/eclipse. Thanks!

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <iostream>

void sampleImage(const IplImage* arr, float idx0, float idx1, CvScalar& res)
{
  if(idx0<0 || idx1<0 || idx0>(cvGetSize(arr).height-1) || idx1>(cvGetSize(arr).width-1)){
    res.val[0]=0;
    res.val[1]=0;
    res.val[2]=0;
    res.val[3]=0;
    return;
  }
  float idx0_fl=floor(idx0);
  float idx0_cl=ceil(idx0);
  float idx1_fl=floor(idx1);
  float idx1_cl=ceil(idx1);

  CvScalar s1=cvGet2D(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_fl);
  CvScalar s2=cvGet2D(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_cl);
  CvScalar s3=cvGet2D(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_cl);
  CvScalar s4=cvGet2D(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_fl);
  float x = idx0 - idx0_fl;
  float y = idx1 - idx1_fl;
  res.val[0]= s1.val[0]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2.val[0]*(1-x)*y + s3.val[0]*x*y + s4.val[0]*x*(1-y);
  res.val[1]= s1.val[1]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2.val[1]*(1-x)*y + s3.val[1]*x*y + s4.val[1]*x*(1-y);
  res.val[2]= s1.val[2]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2.val[2]*(1-x)*y + s3.val[2]*x*y + s4.val[2]*x*(1-y);
  res.val[3]= s1.val[3]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2.val[3]*(1-x)*y + s3.val[3]*x*y + s4.val[3]*x*(1-y);
}

float xscale;
float yscale;
float xshift;
float yshift;

float getRadialX(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){
  x = (x*xscale+xshift);
  y = (y*yscale+yshift);
  float res = x+((x-cx)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
  return res;
}

float getRadialY(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){
  x = (x*xscale+xshift);
  y = (y*yscale+yshift);
  float res = y+((y-cy)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
  return res;
}

float thresh = 1;
float calc_shift(float x1,float x2,float cx,float k){
  float x3 = x1+(x2-x1)*0.5;
  float res1 = x1+((x1-cx)*k*((x1-cx)*(x1-cx)));
  float res3 = x3+((x3-cx)*k*((x3-cx)*(x3-cx)));

  //  std::cerr<<"x1: "<<x1<<" - "<<res1<<" x3: "<<x3<<" - "<<res3<<std::endl;

  if(res1>-thresh && res1 < thresh)
    return x1;
  if(res3<0){
    return calc_shift(x3,x2,cx,k);
  }
  else{
    return calc_shift(x1,x3,cx,k);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  IplImage* src = cvLoadImage( argv[1], 1 );
  IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src),src->depth,src->nChannels);
  IplImage* dst2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src),src->depth,src->nChannels);
  float K=atof(argv[3]);
  float centerX=atoi(argv[4]);
  float centerY=atoi(argv[5]);
  int width = cvGetSize(src).width;
  int height = cvGetSize(src).height;

  xshift = calc_shift(0,centerX-1,centerX,K);
  float newcenterX = width-centerX;
  float xshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterX-1,newcenterX,K);

  yshift = calc_shift(0,centerY-1,centerY,K);
  float newcenterY = height-centerY;
  float yshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterY-1,newcenterY,K);
  //  scale = (centerX-xshift)/centerX;
  xscale = (width-xshift-xshift_2)/width;
  yscale = (height-yshift-yshift_2)/height;

  std::cerr<<xshift<<" "<<yshift<<" "<<xscale<<" "<<yscale<<std::endl;
  std::cerr<<cvGetSize(src).height<<std::endl;
  std::cerr<<cvGetSize(src).width<<std::endl;

  for(int j=0;j<cvGetSize(dst).height;j++){
    for(int i=0;i<cvGetSize(dst).width;i++){
      CvScalar s;
      float x = getRadialX((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,K);
      float y = getRadialY((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,K);
      sampleImage(src,y,x,s);
      cvSet2D(dst,j,i,s);

    }
  }
#if 0
  cvNamedWindow( "Source1", 1 );
  cvShowImage( "Source1", dst);
  cvWaitKey(0);
#endif

  cvSaveImage(argv[2],dst,0);

#if 0
  for(int j=0;j<cvGetSize(src).height;j++){
    for(int i=0;i<cvGetSize(src).width;i++){
      CvScalar s;
      sampleImage(src,j+0.25,i+0.25,s);
      cvSet2D(dst,j,i,s);
    }
  }

  cvNamedWindow( "Source1", 1 );
  cvShowImage( "Source1", src);
  cvWaitKey(0);
#endif

}
```

Comment: Those are Unix includes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on a quick look at this source file, you shouldn't need either of those includes. You definitely don't need `getopt` here, as you're not using the `getopt` functions it defines. Just remove those includes, and see if things don't just work.

Answer (score 7):

`<unistd.h>` is the Unix standard header and is not found on Windows. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unistd.h

I don't know about `<getopt.h>`.

It seems that your code is written for a Unix-based machine, not Windows.

Comment: getopt.h is a gnu libc header with utility functions to parse command line arguments. Example [there](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt).